# Problema con RecyclerView + CardView + OnClick en Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Llevo dos días desesperado, de un día para otro la app dejó de funcionar correctamente. Os comento:

Principalmente el error es que tengo un `RecyclerView` con varios objetos y si pulsas en uno de ellos se abre su ficha. Pues de un día para otro esto dejó de pasar, pulso sobre cualquier objeto y no hace nada. Pero si hago scroll y carga más elementos y vuelvo al primero y le pulso si funciona.
Lo más extraño es que esto en versión `debug` funciona correctamente pero en versión `release` no (cuando firmo el apk). Muy extraño.

Estos objetos están compuestos por un `CardView` y un `ConstraintLayout` en su interior que alberga todos los elementos.

Tambien me pasa que botones que he creado con `ConstraintLayout` y en su interior hay un texto y una imagen, solo funciona el evento del OnClick cuando pulso en lo que es el `ConstraintLayout` si lo hago en la imagen o el texto no ocurre nada.

Creo que tiene algo que ver con el `CardView` como elemento root o los `ConstraintLayout`

Se me olvidó decir que tengo otra app complementaria a esta que utiliza el mismo sistema y en esa sí funciona. He revisado el código y están igual implementadas.

item view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/CardView.Light"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/foto"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:visibility="visible"
            card_view:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/perro" />

        <Space
            android:id="@+id/top_space"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_space" />

        <Space
            android:id="@+id/bottom_space"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/foto" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/negro_50"
            card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_space"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_space" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bandera"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/fpais"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fpais"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_b_desc" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fpais"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="País"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/invisible"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bandera"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/owner"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:tint="@color/blanco"
            card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/fpais"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fpais"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/nav_protes" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/invisible"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:padding="0.7dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/owner"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/owner"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/owner"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nombre"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Nombre"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:textColor="#DE000000"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tipo"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/num_favs"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/foto"
            card_view:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/first_names" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tipo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Especie"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textColor="#8A000000"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/nombre"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nombre"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/num_favs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tipo"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ic_favs"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/nombre" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_favs"
            android:layout_width="11dp"
            android:layout_height="11dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/num_favs"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/num_favs"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_fav" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/estado"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@color/estado_9"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:text="@string/estado_9"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textColor="@color/blanco"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tipo" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

item adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.miwuki.petshelter.R;
import com.miwuki.petshelter.models.animal.Animal;
import com.miwuki.petshelter.mvp.presenter.LocationPresenter;
import com.miwuki.petshelter.utils.OnLoadMoreListener;
import com.miwuki.petshelter.utils.Recursos;
import com.miwuki.petshelter.utils.RecyclerItemClickListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class AnimalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private List<Animal> lista;
    private Context mContext;
    private RecyclerItemClickListener recyclerItemClickListener;

    private final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
    private final int VIEW_PROG = 0;

    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
    private boolean loading;
    private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;


    public AnimalAdapter(List<Animal> list, RecyclerItemClickListener recyclerItemClickListener) {
        this.lista = list;
        this.recyclerItemClickListener = recyclerItemClickListener;
    }

    public AnimalAdapter(List<Animal> list, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerItemClickListener recyclerItemClickListener) {
        this.lista = list;
        this.recyclerItemClickListener = recyclerItemClickListener;

        final GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = (GridLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                totalItemCount = gridLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                lastVisibleItem = gridLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

                if (!loading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                        onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                    }
                    loading = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class AnimalHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.foto)
        ImageView foto;
        @BindView(R.id.nombre)
        TextView nombre;
        @BindView(R.id.tipo)
        TextView especie;
        @BindView(R.id.estado)
        TextView estado;
        @BindView(R.id.num_favs)
        TextView seguidores;
        @BindView(R.id.fpais)
        TextView pais;
        @BindView(R.id.bandera)
        ImageView bandera;
        @BindView(R.id.owner)
        ImageView owner;
        @BindView(R.id.invisible)
        ImageView invisible;

        public AnimalHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }

    public class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.progress)
        ProgressBar progressBar;

        public ProgressViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        mContext = parent.getContext();

        if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.animal_item, parent, false);
            return new AnimalHolder(v);
        }
        else {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.progress, parent, false);
            return new ProgressViewHolder(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (holder instanceof AnimalHolder) {
            final Animal animal = lista.get(position);
            AnimalHolder h = ((AnimalHolder) holder);

            h.nombre.setText(animal.getNombre());
//            h.pais.setText(Pais.getPais(mContext, animal.getPais()));
            h.pais.setText(LocationPresenter.getProvincia(mContext, animal.getPais(), animal.getProvincia()));
            h.especie.setText(Recursos.getStringByName(mContext, "especie_"+animal.getEspecie()));
            h.seguidores.setText(String.valueOf(animal.getSeguidores()));
            h.invisible.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            if(animal.isValidado()) {
                h.estado.setText(Recursos.getStringByName(mContext, "estado_"+animal.getEstado()));
                h.estado.setBackgroundColor(Recursos.getColorByName(mContext, "estado_"+animal.getEstado()));
            }
            else {
                if(animal.sinValidar()) {
                    h.estado.setText(Recursos.getStringByName(mContext, "no_validado"));
                    h.estado.setBackgroundColor(Recursos.getColorByName(mContext, "no_validado"));
                }
                else if(animal.isDenegado()) {
                    h.estado.setText(Recursos.getStringByName(mContext, "denegado"));
                    h.estado.setBackgroundColor(Recursos.getColorByName(mContext, "denegado"));
                }
            }

            if(animal.isParticular()) {
                h.owner.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.nav_perfil));
            }
            else h.owner.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.nav_home));

            if(animal.isInvisible()) {
                h.invisible.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            Recursos.setBandera(mContext, animal.getPais(), h.bandera);

            if(animal.hasFotoPerfil())
                Recursos.setFoto(mContext, animal, h.foto);
            else h.foto.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.perro));

            h.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    recyclerItemClickListener.onItemClick(position);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        }
    }

    public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
        this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return lista.get(position) != null ? VIEW_ITEM : VIEW_PROG;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lista.size();
    }

    public Animal getItem(int position) { return lista.get(position); }

    public void addItem(Animal animal) {
        if(animal != null){
            lista.add(animal);
            notifyItemInserted(lista.size()-1);
        }
    }

    public void setList(List<Animal> lista) {
        this.lista.clear();
        this.lista = new ArrayList<>(lista);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addItems(List<Animal> lista) {
        if(!lista.isEmpty())
            this.lista.addAll(lista);
        notifyItemRangeInserted(this.lista.size()-1, lista.size());
    }

    public void replaceItem(int position, Animal animal){
        lista.set(position, animal);
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        lista.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public void removeLastItem() {
        this.removeItem(lista.size()-1);
    }
    public void addNullItem() {
        lista.add(null);
        notifyItemInserted(lista.size()-1);
    }

    public void setLoaded(){
        loading = false;
    }

}
```

Paso del listener al adapter:
- El `adapter` lo recibe como parámetro en el `constructor`.

```
adapter = new AnimalAdapter(lista, recyclerView, recyclerItemClickListener);

private RecyclerItemClickListener recyclerItemClickListener = new RecyclerItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position) {
            Transition.init(getActivity(), FichaAnimalActivity.class, Consts.ARG_ANIMAL, adapter.getItem(position), Consts.ARG_USER, mUser);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Podrías colocar las clases de AnimalHolder y algunos datos para poder replicar el problema.

Comment: He añadido la clase AnimalAdpater entera, lso datos vienen directamente de una api y los muestro tal cual.

Comment: Todo parece en orden. Intenta agregarle `android:clickable="true"` y `android:focusable="true"` al `CardView`. ¿El padre que contiene al `RecyclerView` tiene dichas propiedades mencionadas anteriormente? ¿Estás haciendo `NestedScrolling` (El padre es scrollable)? O Estás utilizando Spans en los TextViews? Algo te debe estar robando el foco. Si no funciona, intenta 3 cosas: prueba implementar el onClick en la clase del holder e imprimir logs en vez de utilizar el listener; actualiza las librerías o implementar onItemClickListener del `RecyclerView`. Muestra como pasas el listener a tu adapter.

Comment: @Andrespengineer voy a probar todo eso y os cuento. Y ahora edito la entrada con lo que pides.

Comment: Que haz intentado?

Comment: Perdona he estado de viaje y no pude contestar:
1 - *Intenta agregarle android:clickable="true" y android:focusable="true" al CardView*: Ya lo probé, sigue igual.
2 - *¿El padre que contiene al RecyclerView tiene dichas propiedades mencionadas anteriormente?*: Ya lo probé, sigue igual.
3 - *¿Estás haciendo NestedScrolling (El padre es scrollable)?*: No, el padre no es scrollable. Sólo el RecyclerView.